# Ruby - Sorting by id and grouping by date in hash

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, grouping

I've been struggling with this in a bit and could not get a satisfactory result. I have this hash:

```
{"idprj"=>13351, "prevInicioStr"=>"21/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14473, "prevInicioStr"=>"22/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"23/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"23/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"28/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"28/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14518, "prevInicioStr"=>"29/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14518, "prevInicioStr"=>"29/10/2019"}
{"idprj"=>13351, "prevInicioStr"=>"05/11/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"06/11/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"08/11/2019"}
{"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"13/01/2020"}
```

And I wanted to sort by 'prevInicioStr' AND group by 'idprj' (you can see id 13351 isn't grouped as it should). To get this result I did this:

```
result.sort_by { |hash| [ Date.parse(hash['prevInicioStr']), hash['idprj'] ] }
```

Comment: That is 12 hashes, not one. Do you mean it to be an array of hashes? If so (even though you've selected an answer), please edit to make it so. Also, it would be helpful if you would assign a variable to the array (e.g., `arr = [{...}, {...},...,{...}]`), so that readers could refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it. Also, why did you select the first answer offered? You don't want to see others?

Comment: I've selected as answered because it fits my needs but hey, you're all welcome to comment aswell!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must group first, and then sort (actually, you sort the values):

```
data = [{"idprj"=>13351, "prevInicioStr"=>"21/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14473, "prevInicioStr"=>"22/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"23/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"23/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"28/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"28/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14518, "prevInicioStr"=>"29/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14518, "prevInicioStr"=>"29/10/2019"}, {"idprj"=>13351, "prevInicioStr"=>"05/11/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"06/11/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"08/11/2019"}, {"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"13/01/2020"}]
pp data.group_by { |e| e['idprj'] }
       .transform_values { |values| values.sort_by { |e| e['prevInicioStr'] } }

# {13351=>
#   [{"idprj"=>13351, "prevInicioStr"=>"05/11/2019"},
#    {"idprj"=>13351, "prevInicioStr"=>"21/10/2019"}],
#  14473=>[{"idprj"=>14473, "prevInicioStr"=>"22/10/2019"}],
#  14165=>
#   [{"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"23/10/2019"},
#    {"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"23/10/2019"},
#    {"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"28/10/2019"},
#    {"idprj"=>14165, "prevInicioStr"=>"28/10/2019"}],
#  14518=>
#   [{"idprj"=>14518, "prevInicioStr"=>"29/10/2019"},
#    {"idprj"=>14518, "prevInicioStr"=>"29/10/2019"}],
#  14305=>
#   [{"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"06/11/2019"},
#    {"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"08/11/2019"},
#    {"idprj"=>14305, "prevInicioStr"=>"13/01/2020"}]}
```

Comment: Looks good, the only thing is sorting by date. Wouldnt it be better to use something like `.sort_by { |e| Date.strptime(e['prevInicioStr'], '%d/%m/%Y') }`

Comment: That would be nice, but I don't know if it's needed since `p "05/11/2019" <=> "21/10/2019" # -1;
p "21/10/2019" <=> "05/11/2019" # 1;
p "21/10/2019" <=> "21/10/2019" # 0`.

Comment: Done! Just removed the keys in my code and let only the values and everything is fine now!

Comment: @SebastianPalma It isn't needed in iso8601 format, since the date is represented in the other direction. Currently you're sorting by day, then by month, then by year. Meaning that `"01/01/2050"` comes before `"06/01/1850"`, since `"01"` is smaller than `"06"`.